# Rebar build fails on Erlang R15B02

Tags: erlang, rebar

1. Uninstalled previous version of erlang
2. Installed the latest release R15B02
3. Installed rebar from source

rebar compile fails now with the following error:

```
Uncaught error in rebar_core: {'EXIT',
                               {badarg,
                                [{erlang,make_fun,
                                  [{atom,42,filelib},
                                   {atom,42,wildcard},
                                   {integer,42,1}],
                                  []},
                                 {rebar_subdirs,preprocess,2,[]},
                                 {rebar_core,acc_modules,5,[]},
                                 {rebar_core,process_dir0,6,[]},
                                 {rebar_core,process_commands,2,[]},
                                 {rebar,main,1,[]},
                                 {erl_eval,do_apply,6,
                                  [{file,"erl_eval.erl"},{line,572}]},
                                 {escript,eval_exprs,5,
                                  [{file,"escript.erl"},{line,850}]}]}} make: *** [all] Error 1
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Please add rebar version and environment information.

Answer (score 0):

The error says that it can't make fun out of **fun filelib:wildcard/1** (BIF) in https://github.com/basho/rebar/blob/master/src/rebar_subdirs.erl which is perfectly ok thing to do.

So it looks like you got something wrong in your environment. Aren't you using Windows or something else similarly ridiculous?

Alternatively you can try to do the same thing with precompiled rebar, which is located here: https://github.com/basho/rebar/wiki/rebar